# Performance Issue when playing Rage

Tags: technical-issues, performance, rage

I recently installed rage on my PC, expecting to run smoothly after i played it on a less powerful pc having a decent FPS, BUT! Here comes the plot twist, because after I start a new game, (the pre-rendered cinematics running okay ofcourse) and get in the actual game, I  literally get **0FPS**, the game 'updates' every 2-3 seconds so it takes like 2 minutes open start menu etc.

My PC is more than enough for this game, so what can be the problem? Am I missing something?

0FPS PC SPECS:

- Processor:   AMD Phenom II x4 965 Black Edition @3,9Ghz
- RAM:     8GB Kingston 1333MHz
- Videocard:   MSI HD6790
- OS:  Windows 8
- MOBO:        Gigabyte
- HDD:     WD 500GB, SAMSUNG 1,5TB

The PC that runs it perfectly:

- Processor:   Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 @ 3Ghz
- RAM:     4GB Kingston
- Videocard:   GT640-DCSL-2GD3
- OS:  Windows 7
- MOBO:        Gigabyte
- HDD:     WD 500GB

Comment: If you can't put in the effort of writing your PC specs, how do you expect people to take the effort of troubleshooting your issue?

Comment: I linked the pc specs, not because i'm lazy, but because it's easy, and not that necessary for this problem because it may be because of my video card which I wrote into the title of this post.

Comment: I believe PC specs play a rather large role in trying to answer your question here.  If your graphics card can handle it, it's quite important.

Comment: Okay then, I edited the OP, now it contains both PC Specs, but im 99% sure that its not HW related.

Comment: Which hard drive is Rage installed onto?  It looks like it should work find regardless, but perhaps the hard drive is going.

Comment: It's installed on WD 500GB (7200rpm, so it should be fine) Every other game runs fine, but i cant seem to fix this one